# (R, dplyr) How to aggregate-window data where rows must be conditionally included?

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I've googled around, but have not found anything similar to this, but I'm hoping what I'm trying to do has already been done by someone else before.

1. I have a set of data with timestamps.
2. I need a running cumulative count of transactions per second - calculated as a true rolling second window.  Would be nice to just truncate / round off to nearest second but that wont be enough for my use case.

| #Timestamp | Current TPS |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00:00.1 | 1 | ................................................................................................ |
| 00:00:00.2 | 2 |  |
| 00:00:00.3 | 3 |  |
| 00:00:00.4 | 4 |  |
| 00:00:00.5 | 5 |  |
| 00:00:00.6 | 6 |  |
| 00:00:00.7 | 7 |  |
| 00:00:00.8 | 8 |  |
| 00:00:00.9 | 9 |  |
| 00:00:01.0 | 10 | ....................................10 TPS here............................................................ |
| 00:00:01.1 | 10 |  |
| 00:00:01.2 | 10 | .................................... still 10 TPS here............................................................ |
| 00:00:01.4 | 9 | ............ only 9 here, because no event at 00:00:01.3 |
| 00:00:01.5 | 9 |  |
| 00:00:01.5 | 10 |  |
| 00:00:01.8 | 8 |  |

Initially, I was planning to calculate a time interval difference between rows, but that doesn't solve the question of how to determine which rows should be included or excluded in the aggregate window.

This morning, I thought about mutating a new column that is just the subsecond portion of time. Then, I use that new column as a substraction on the time column, and cumsum it inside a 2nd if_else mutate that does a look-back over last X number of rows?

Does that sound reasonable? Have I overlooked some other/better approach?

Comment: Slide package is great for this: https://davisvaughan.github.io/slider/reference/slide_index.html

Comment: thanks @JonSpring, I will definitely check that package out. looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

timestamps <- c("00:00:00.1", "00:00:00.2", "00:00:00.3", "00:00:00.4", "00:00:00.5", "00:00:00.6", "00:00:00.7", "00:00:00.8", "00:00:00.9", "00:00:01.0", "00:00:01.1", "00:00:01.2", "00:00:01.4", "00:00:01.5", "00:00:01.5", "00:00:01.8") %>%
  lubridate::hms %>%     # convert to a time period in hours minutes seconds
  as.numeric  # convert that to a number of seconds

slider::slide_index_dbl(timestamps,
            timestamps,
            ~length(.x),   # = how many timestamps are in the window
            .before = .99)  # Note: using 1 here gave me an incorrect result, 
            # presumably due to floating point arithmetic errors 
            # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 10 10  9 10 10  8
```